# How to sync Facebook chat on my web browser and iPhone application?

Tags: ios, facebook, xmpp, chat, xmppframework

I have developed a Facebook Chat application for iPhone using the XMPP framework.

How do I sync between Facebook chat in the browser and in my application.

If I send a message to a user from my application, it shows up in the browser.
If a user sends me a message. It shows in both places.

The case I am not able to handle is when I send a message from the browser. It should show up in my application as well, but it doesn't.

I want to be able to run my application on multiple devices, and any message I send or receive should be shown in all devices.

Comment: I just found out that XMPP does not store chat history. So that is not possible. Is there any workaround?

Comment: I don't know if Facebook chat supports it, but XMPP has an extension for archiving: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html